# Changing Array values in for each loop not working java

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I am confused as to what isn't working in my code for a class. I am attempting to change array values in a for each loop, and it prints correctly from the for each loop but doesn't store the correct values afterwords. I expect both results to be `{2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0}`, but the second print shows `{10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}`.

```
double speed [] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(double each : speed){
    int i = 0;
    each *= 2;
    speed[i] = each;
    i++;
}

for(double each : speed){
    System.out.println("\n" + each);
}
```

Comment: setting `i` to 0 at every iteration doesn't help for sure

Answer (score 3):

You declare `i` inside the loop, so the `i++` has no effect, it is re-initialized to 0 at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrea said in his answer, the problem is that you're redeclaring `i` at every iteration. So what you actually want is

```
double speed [] = {1,2,3,4,5};

int i = 0;
for(double each : speed){
    each *= 2;
    speed[i] = each;
    i++;
}

for(double each : speed){
    System.out.println("\n" + each);
}
```

*BUT*, unless this is a toy example, it's not, IMHO, the right construct. Since you need to access the index on what you're iterating on, and `speed` is a simple array, a normal `for` is probably what you actually need. So

```
double speed [] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int i = 0; i < speed.length; i++){
    speed[i] *= 2;
}

for(double each : speed){
    System.out.println("\n" + each);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the output is correct. But if you want to print `{2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0}`, then the code should be

```
double speed [] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int i = 0;
    for(double each : speed){           
        each *= 2;
        speed[i] = each;
        i++;
    }
    for(double each : speed){
        System.out.println("\n" + each);
    }
```

i.e. the variable **i** should be initialized outside the *for each* loop.